# Coroutine Actor with Android MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, coroutine

I need to implement `Kotlin Coroutines` on MVVM pattern, I try to test this using `actors` on `ViewModel`, the problem is that I don't understand how to use it propertly.
I understand that I need to send calls from the view in actor `offer/send` method, But how controll it? I need to make each sealed class for each viewmodel?

The actor:

```
private val gradeActor = viewModelScope.actor<ActorCommand<String>>(Dispatchers.Main) {
        for (command in channel) {
            when (command) {
                is ActorCommand.REGISTER -> {

                    // do
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

The sealed class:

```
sealed class ActorCommand<out T> {
    class REGISTER<T>(val id: Int, val name: String, val response: SendChannel<T>? = null) : ActorCommand<T>()
    class REMOVE<T>(val id: Int, val response: SendChannel<T>? = null) : ActorCommand<T>()
    class QUERY<T>(val response: SendChannel<T>) : ActorCommand<T>()
}
```

I use this sealed class to send the data (register send the name and ID of my data and the `ViewModel` call repository with retrofit).

But the "problem" is that...
I use this sealed class to send data and communicate to my `ViewModel`, but not all my views use this same data, I have views that need to send `Double`, `Objects` and many other things... I need to create a sealed class with different methods for each `viewmodel/view`?
Don't have another choice?

I think it's not a good practics (maybe I wrong)...
It's possible to use 1 sealed class to all?
Or It's not good use sealed class for this and have another think to do.

Sample:
For TwoAfViewModel I use:

```
sealed class TwoFaCommand {
    class VERIFY(val code: String, val sessionId: String) : TwoFaCommand()
    class CONFIRM(val secretKey: String, val manualCode: String, val code: String) : TwoFaCommand()
    class SAVE(val secretKey: String, val manualCode: String, val code: String) : TwoFaCommand()
}
```

For LoginViewModel I use:

```
sealed class LoginCommand {
    class LOGIN(val email: String, val password: String) : LoginCommand()
    class LOGIN_VALIDATE(val email: String, val password: String) : LoginCommand()
    class SAVE_USER_DATA(val email: String, val password: String) : LoginCommand()
    object USER_IV : LoginCommand()
}
```

On actor call (LoginViewModel):

```
private val eventActor = viewModelScope.actor<LoginCommand>(Dispatchers.Main, Channel.RENDEZVOUS) {
        for (command in channel) {
            when (command) {
                is LoginCommand.LOGIN -> {
                    loadingStateLiveData.postValue(true)
                    loginLiveData.postValue(loginRepository.getLogin(Login(command.email, command.password)))
                    loadingStateLiveData.postValue(false)
                }
                is LoginCommand.SAVE_USER_DATA -> {
                    loginSavedRepository.saveUserData(command.email, command.password)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It's really necessary to create a sealed class for each viewmodel and channel communication? (Just like I'm doing)